# How to get each monitor's absolute coords when using twinview on Linux?

Tags: linux, window, desktop, x11

I have two monitors connected to a Linux PC and i'm using nVidia's twinview mode to span my desktop across both monitors. I've developed a piece of software that opens a window which i want to center in monitor 2. The following are the two resolutions of my monitors:

1. 1280x1024
2. 1920x1200

Combined, twinview treats this as one huge desktop with a resolution of 3200x1200.

Because these two monitors are joined together as one large desktop i can't just center the window in monitor 2. How can i get the absolute coords of the second montor to center my window within it?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because i've no idea what to do, hence the question!